# Not able to get the updated value from modal back to controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal and doing some process to update a value from modal and it is not updating from my controller. Please let me know how to get the value($scope.currentItem.value) back from modal to controller.

```
$scope.showModalForm = function(data, index) {
      $scope.currentItem = data; 
  ngDialog.open(
          {
              template: '/scripts/app/panel/MyInfo.html',
              controller: 'MyInfoController',                
              scope: $scope,
              width:"50%",

          })
};

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MyInfoController', function ($scope,$http, $log) {
        $scope.submit = function() {
            // OPen modal and process sucessfully need to send the approve back to controller
     if(process) {
            $scope.currentItem.value = "Corrected";
     }
     if(!process) {
         $scope.currentItem.value = "Wrong";
      }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the ngDialog docs:

> Scope object that will be passed to the dialog. If you use a controller with separate $scope service this object will be passed to the $scope.$parent param

So, in MyInfoController you need to reference $scope of the parent controller as $scope.$parent instead of $scope.  Like this:

```
$scope.$parent.currentItem.value = "Corrected";
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/43mDoWSuucmRRvK0q2tz?p=preview)